# Limiting Scope on URL Rewrite Outbound Rules

Tags: iis-7, url-rewriting, iis-7.5, url-rewrite-module

We have set a series of outbound rules to add some URL parameter at the end of every A HREF, AREA, BASE, FORM, FRAME, HEAD, IFRAME, etc. tags. Everything works fine.

The question we have is whether there is a way to restrict the scope of these rules only to a specific section of the HTML response (i.e. between two specific HTML comments). In other words we would like to have the rules behave as follows:

```
<html>
....
** NO RULES APPLIED HERE **
....
<!-- START SECTION -->
....
** RULES APPLIED HERE **
....
<!-- END SECTION -->
....
** NO RULES APPLIED HERE **
....
</html>
```

I think this is not possible but maybe one of you guys has a solution to this problem?
Thanks in advance,
-FG